# German sci-fi tv show with minimalist music, 70's or 80's?

Tags: story-identification

Some years ago, if I remember correctly, I was looking for sci-fi TV shows on Youtube, so I caught some snippets/inserts on Youtube, which were apparently from a German sci-fi TV show. It had rather minimalistic/noisy music, and there was a sort of a brutalist architecture vibe in the show. Unfortunately, I'm not a German speaker, so I didn't understand the story, nor did I remember the title. But as far as I can remember, it was in color, and the fashion/graininess of picture suggested it was from the late 70s or early 80s (so it would have been either East or West German production).

So now when I look for German sci-fi TV shows, all I can find are shows like "Alpha Alpha" (

-> similar picture quality to what I remember, so probably close in period, but way too funky music in this trailer), or "Alpha 0.7 - Der Feind in dir" (that one is way too new).

I'm guessing the show was sci-fi due to some unseen computers or something (or maybe time travel), as there were no obvious "future technologies" (such as  lasers, holograms, or even computers), I think the architecture and interior design was (and the minimalist electronic music) was what mostly gave the association of "future" in that show.

I am aware this is quite vague description, but if anyone recognizes anything from this description, I'd love to hear a hint!

EDIT: I also remember the clothing was basically "normal" from the period, nothing (extremely) sci-fi-ish...

Comment: Welcome to the site. You have a good start here. If you could take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] in any more details so that it is less vague, that would be great. Every little bit helps us.

Comment: Note that answer below is provided by OP.

Answer (score 3):

OK, got it finally - it is Welt am Draht (World on a Wire) from 1973, director Rainer Werner Fassbinder, television serial in two parts (so not quite a TV series, I was wrong there). There is a decent trailer with subtitles (so I could see, indeed it was sci-fi due to something with a computer): here it is - I find the soundtrack (being abstract electronic noise) awesome: